# Django Default language not working

Tags: python, django

I have a django app which supports two languages English and Arabic i need to change the default language to Arabic

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ar'
LANGUAGES = (
    (u'ar', _('Arabic')),
    (u'en', _('English')),
)
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = False
```

but when I open 127.0.0.1:8000 it redirects to English 127.0.0.1:8000/en not to Arabic

url.py  include

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
'',
url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
)
```

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES for django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware.  More on implementing that is available from this url: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference

I hope this is useful.

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/

Comment: thank you for give me your attention . . but the  locale.LocaleMiddleware is included in my MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES

Answer (score 0):

Your urlpatterns look wrong to me. `django.conf.urls.i18n` defines the set_language urlpatterns, what you probably want is to include it normally  and apply `i18n_patterns` to *your* urls only, like:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
)

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'', include('your.urls')),
)
```

Comment: thank you for respond , 
i  just forget "u"  when i am copying the line `urlpatterns = i18n_patterns `

i am just include to the question the related lines only . .   the url work correctly when i change it to "ar" and "en"
so i guess the problem not the urls

Answer (score 0):

You should edit only one thing to make it work properly: 
**LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ar-eg'**

Answer (score 0):

Django will use the `Accept-Language` header in the HTTP request to determine the default language, even if the `LANGUAGE_CODE` variable is set to something else.

Add this middleware to your middleware classes **BEFORE** the `LocaleMiddleware` to bypass and override this check:

in middleware.py:

```
class ForceDefaultLanguageMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.META.has_key('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'):
            del request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']
```

in settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'yourproject.middleware.ForceDefaultLanguageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    ...
]
```